# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::morphWith

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-5.8

Getting trouble with the following code

```
$feed = Feed::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->with(['feedable' => function (MorphTo $morphTo) {
                        $morphTo->morphWith([
                            Post::class => ['user', 'images', 'likes', 'comments', 'comments.user'],
                            GroupPost::class => ['user', 'images', 'likes', 'comments', 'comments.user', 'group']
                        ]);
                    }])
                    ->paginate(10);
```

User the reference for this from https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Not getting what went wrong.
Getting error like **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::morphWith**

While the lazy loading works fine

```
$feed = Feed::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->with('feedable')
                    ->paginate(10)
                    ->loadMorph('feedable', [
                        Post::class => ['user', 'images', 'likes', 'comments', 'comments.user'],
                        GroupPost::class => ['user', 'images', 'likes', 'comments', 'comments.user', 'group'],
                    ]);
```

Please help with this issue.

Comment: What's your exact Laravel version?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Laravel 5.8

Comment: What's the third number (5.8.x)? What does `composer show` show for `laravel/framework`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Laravel 5.8.8

Comment: `morphWith()` was introduced in Laravel 5.8.22. You need to update your dependencies.

Comment: Can you help with the procedure? @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: Run `composer update`.